# Center text in h3 with height

Tags: css

So I've got a `h3`

```
<h3>someText<h3>
```

The `h3` has a height and a background image

```
h3
{
height:30px;
background-image:url();
background-reat: repeat-x;
}
```

now I want the text in the `h3` to align to the middle of the element but it always floats the text to the top: 
[image]

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if who designed CSS vertical alignment has been caught and is now in jail or not.

Comment: @6502 I know! The number of times I stumbled upon and thought "Amazing!" followed by "Borderline pointless!"… [Good article on it here](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `line-height` to match the `height`:

```
h3
{
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
background-image:url();
background-reat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: @MilchePatern that's what this does — I think it's what the user's after, too: "…I want the text in the h3 to align to the middle of the element but it always floats the text to the top"

Comment: The code I've provided already achieves the desired result. `vertical-align` only applies to tabular elements. It would be redundant if it weren't also ineffective in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

If your `<h3>` element contains multiple lines of text, setting the `line-height` property won't work as suggested by the other answers.

If you do not have to support `lteIE7`, you can use `display: table-cell` combined with the `vertical-align` property:

```
h3 {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add `line-height:30px;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height` to solve this

```
h3 {
    height:30px;
    background-image:url();
    background-reat: repeat-x;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h3 {
    ...
    /* those 2 lines are what you need */
    line-height:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, to be precise about the problem with this: `vertical-align` [only affects inline or table-cell elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align). So by default, it will have no effect on an `<h3>`, unless extraneous styles (with unwarranted side-effects) are applied to it. Besides, it is redundant when the `line-height` has already achieved exactly what was asked for.